# Is it acceptable for a submit button to have a name attribute?

Tags: html, coding-style, standards, w3c-validation

Usually, a submit button works fine without a `name` attribute. However, there are occasions where there's a need to have two submit buttons for the same form, hence making use of the `name` attribute to identify which button was clicked on the server side.

To clarify I am talking about: `<input type="submit" name="foo">`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is entirely acceptable.

The specification [has explicit rules for how to determine which submit button was successful](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2), which would be useless if you couldn't give the element a name.