# What is use of name attribute in submit button php

Tags: php, forms, button, attributes, submit

```
<form action="php.php" method="post">
<input name="username"></input>
<input name="password"></input>
<button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

what is use of name attribute in the submit button?. thanks for telling

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose is to be able to detect which button has been clicked to send the form, in a situation where you have more than one submit button on the form.

In most cases, like the one described in the question, there will be no need to name the submit button.

Check also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16387519/14066311).